# JavaScript Form uploading files

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, web

I am new to web development, I was going through someones code, in that there was a form which allowed to upload files.

onclick the form called a function `send(this)`

So in the js function was declared like this

```
function send(form){
 if(form[0]==null || form[0].files[0]==null){
  return -1;
 }
}
```

I dont understand what this `form[0]` and `form[0].files[0]` are? What does the `[0]` represent? Is this an array or what? if its an array it was not declared anywhere in the code, but still the code was working

Answer (score 0):

A form element is a bit of an oddball in that it is *array-like*. The form controls it contains are added to the element object using zero based indexing the same as an array. These controls are also stored in `form.elements` which is also array-like.

The short answer then to your question  is `form[0]` is the first form control in the form which in your case appears to be a file input.

Sample of accessors of the elements:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

console.log('"form.length" =', form.length)
console.log('"form[0]" =', form[0])
Array.from(form).forEach(el => console.log('"forEach el"', el))
console.log('"form[0]===form.elements[0]" =', form[0] === form.elements[0])
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="file" />
  <input placeholder="Text input" />
  <select></select>
</form>
```